# Optimization - how is using a evolutionary algorithm different than using gradient descent with multiple start points

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, gradient-descent

Looking at [evolutionary algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolutionary_algorithm) as a way to optimize a function, it seems like one of the biggest advantages of them is being able to work in non-convext functions. Because you have many actors in every generation, even if one branch of evolution gets stuck in a local minimum (/ maximum), someone else will go on (randomailty and mutation).

How is that different than having a gradient descent style algorithm just start at many random starting points?

Comment: One difference is that the gradient method moves each point in the specific direction of the gradient, while the evolutionary algorithm allows for random mutations, i.e. it does not force the agent to move in a specific direction. And, of course, in evolutionary algorithms you can things like cross-over, which you can't in gradient methods.

Comment: @Bram28 but the reason these are good is so that unlike gradient descent, in evolutionary algorithms you can't get 'stuck' rolling down a slope into a local maximum...

Comment: Exactly. Of course, if you had enough agents in the gradient method so that you are guaranteed that at least one of them will get to the global maximum, then that's great, but in practice that rarely happens. So yes, with the gradient method you are stuck to whatever local regions the actors are initally placed, while the evolutionary algorithm has at least the potential to explore the whole space (... Though it may take a *really long* time ...)

Comment: But if you can ittereate GD and place more actors? In infinite time both will work, but does EA have an advantage?

Comment: Most implementation of evolutionary algorithms use a randomized gradient for doing the descent, and use multiple starting points (recreating new starting points in a random way, this last part being very complicated and almost impossible to generalize to any kind of smooth function)

Answer (score 2):

I think the difference should be more considered as to *what kind of search space* you are interested in, rather than the exact behaviour at local minima.

For extremely noisy and discontinuous objective functions, using the gradient is essentially useless and it is better to spend computation time exploring disparate parts of space rather than walk around locally. For smooth, convex objectives, using an evolutionary approach is computationally wasteful instead.

As others have mentioned, given enough restarts, one should in principle find the global maximum (although pathological cases can exist, where the local minimums "lure" away any agents from the global extremum). The EA will not have this pathology.

I think it is important to note that, in practice for noisy objective functions, gradient descent is modified to be [stochastic gradient descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent) or [simulated annealing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing). Both are ways to escape local minima and can also be used in conjunction with random restarts.

For evolutionary algorithms, one modification is the use of [memetic algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memetic_algorithm), where one combines the global evolutionary optimization approach with local (often gradient-descent-style searches). So the two approaches are less different than one might think.

Answer (score 0):

Even with a lot of actors randomly placed in the solution space, the gradient method will still force those actors to find the local maximum, so it is still possible that no actor will find the global maximum.

On the other hand, for the evolutionary algorithm there is always a chance that through random mutations the actors find the global maximum.  In fact, even with one actor per generation this is possible.

Comment: Here's what I'm thinking:

GD - with infinite actors, you'll reach a global minimun;

EA - with infinite ittirations you'll breed an actor that reached the global minimum;

The problem of when to stop would presist with both though, wouldn't it? Or is there a solution for that with EA?

Comment: @byteSlayer yes. And (in general) you never attain the global minimum, but you have a better and better approximation to it